# PayPal / Google Checkout or Alternative HELP?

Tags: javascript, html, api, paypal, google-checkout

I am exploring options to enable a checkout on a website for a friend. The requirements for the checkout are seemingly simple. The product in question can be viewed here:

http://www.cedartimemachines.com/CCB.html

I have worked with PayPal and Google checkout to accomplish this, however the buy buttons only allow for 1 drop down menu with prices per product. What I need is to have the all the features elected by the customer to add up and proceed to the checkout with that price.

I have a thorough knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript, but I do not have a clue when it comes to server side stuff or eCommerce. Any help would GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at https://stripe.com/ - their API will let you set up your form however you'd like, and then have them do all the heavy lifting for the billing. You'll get a confirmation token back once the transaction completes, and can use that to deliver the product.

Check out [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) to see if it'll work for you.